# Camel-Hystrix-EIP : Is it possible to dynamically select onFallback or onFallbackViaNetwork based on content body in exchange?

Tags: apache-camel, hystrix

Existing Route:

```
from("direct:test").id(id+"direct:test")
.hystrix()
.id("testHystrix").hystrixConfiguration().corePoolSize(corePoolSize)
.end()
.process(requestProcessor)
.to(endPoint)
.onFallbackViaNetwork()
.toD("${headers.fallbackEndPoint}")
.endHystrix();
```

Is it possible to chose fallback logic dynamically either onFallback() or onFallbackViaNetwork() based on the body in exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can have 2 routes where each route has one or the other, and then route to the appropriate route based on the message body content.